# Importing a large SQL script into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, scripting, sql, query

I'm trying to move a database from our production server to our test server. I've used Microsoft's [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en) to create a script containing the schema and data for the production database.

However **I can't figure out how to load this script into our test database.**The resulting script is about 500mb, which isn't 'large' by database standards but large enough that I can't copy and paste it into the query analyzer. Alternatively, when I try and open the file directly with the SQL Server Management Studio it complains

> The operation could not be completed. Not enough storage is available for this operation.

This error happens *before* I select a database, so I believe it is the Management Studio complaining about not having enough memory to load a 500mb file.

Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're only trying to copy it into the query analyzer to run it, maybe you could just create a batch file using OSQL to run it from the command prompt.

Here's the MSDN for OSQL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213090.aspx

Comment: I'd vote you up but it requires 15 rep, but this does seem to be working, thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad it's working.

Comment: The poster doesn't mention the version of SQL Server.  On later versions I would use sqlcmd, this is functionally equivalent to osql though.

Comment: @Joel, The remote server is SQL server 2000, but locally I have the 2005 tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can always take your database offline and detach it. Then you can just copy the physical files over to the other server and attach it. Easy way.

Answer (score 0):

In the future you may want to just use the backup and restore option to move from one server to another.

Comment: Yeah I don't have admin privileges on the production machine, but I have enough privileges to generate a creation script.